# How to set the Maximum value in a Xamarin ProgressBar?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, progress-bar

I'd like to adapt mu progressBar to the length of data that I have, but unfortunately I can't find a solution on how to change the maximum value of the progressBar .

The only thing that I could find is some "progress.Maximum" examples , but the property Maximum is not defined in progressBar Class in Xamarin .

Comment: Why would you set the maximum value ? you could've change the layoutoptions if it means to expand the progressbar.

Comment: Use Xamarin Slider it allow you to set minimum and maximum value

Answer (score 0):

The ProgressBar display progress, so you can bind Silder to ProgressBar to set progress, like this:

```
<StackLayout>
        <ProgressBar
            x:Name="bar"
            Margin="0,166,0,0"
            BindingContext="{x:Reference silder}"
            HeightRequest="20"
            Progress="{Binding Path=Value}"
            VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />

        <Slider
            x:Name="silder"
            Maximum="1"
            Minimum="0.1"
            VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
            Value="0" />
    </StackLayout>
```

[image]